Unable to start Gauge Intellij plugin - where is Gauge installed?
I get the above error when I try to debug using Android Studio v 2024.1.1. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Gauge, as well as adding "%ProgramFiles%\gauge\bin" to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Gauge -> GAUGE_HOME.
I have looked in Program Files and Program Files x86, and I can't find Gauge.
Any assistance would be appreciated.
